# How do I get bar labels in Plotly Graph Objects to display in the same format as the axis?

Tags: python, plotly

I have created a simple bar chart using Python Plotly Graph Objects but I have not been able to find how to get the bar labels to match what is on the y-axis.

Here is my code:

```
occ_data = {"Occupancy":[0.14,0.33,0.42,0.33],
       "Statistics":["Minimum","Average","Maximum","Maximum Average"]}

colours = ["Blue","green","Red","Yellow"]

occ_data_fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=occ_data["Statistics"],
                                y=(occ_data["Occupancy"]), 
                                text=(occ_data["Occupancy"]),
                                textposition="outside",
                                marker_color=colours)])

occ_data_fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat = ".0%")
occ_data_fig.update_layout(title_text="Desk Occupancy Levels for a Typical Company")
```

This results in this visualisation:

[image]

The axis is correctly displaying as percentages, but how can I get the bar labels to? So for example, instead of "0.14" I would like the blue bar to read "14%" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a number format via the `Bar` `texttemplate` parameter. See https://plotly.com/python/reference/bar/#bar-texttemplate. So, in you code, change the call to

```
occ_data_fig=go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=occ_data["Statistics"],
                                y=(occ_data["Occupancy"]), 
                                text=(occ_data["Occupancy"]),
                                textposition="outside",
                                texttemplate="Occupancy: %{y:.1%}",
                                marker_color=colours)])
```

adding a one digit after the decimal percent number.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I could not find it in the documentation myself. I don't see how anyone can beat this answer, but I will leave it open for a while before accepting anyway.